# How to create a repo with multiple forked repos inside

Tags: git, github

I hope you can help me with my problem.
I'd like to create a githup repo with structure like this:

```
My repo
├── cache
│   └── cache files/catalogs
├── resources
│   ├── CatalogA
│   │   ├── RepoA
│   │   ├── RepoB
│   │   └── RepoX
│   ├── CatalogB
│   │   ├── RepoC
│   │   ├── RepoD
│   │   └── RepoY
│   ├── CatalogG
│   ├── CatalogH
│   └── RepoZ
└── config.yml
```

So I would like to have my own repository with forks from other repositories (with my custom changes) so I can pull changes from those repos if there is some changes that I like.

Should I do it with one repo or is it other correct way of doing it?

Thanks You for your time!

Comment: Use submodules?

Comment: Nevermind..... I see you have multiple repos in there. Submodules will probably be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

1. Forget about [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) **forever**
2. Read about [git subtree](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree) and use it:

- each fork is separate repo
- you have one "super-repo", in which some subtrees are your external forks, but you can see and manage it all as one repo for Git (and GitHub also)